# Oledb Connection Hangs VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, oledb, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

I am using an OledbConnection to an AS400 computer. When I have a SQL statement that will return nothing, it just hangs on the adapter command Fill.

```
Function ExecuteOLEDBQuery(ByVal cmdtext As String) As DataTable

    Try
        Dim connString As String = "Provider=IBMDA400;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=@@USERID;Password=@@PASSWORD;Data Source=@@SYSTEM"
        Dim as400 As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connString)
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(cmdtext, as400)
        Dim adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 60 'Doesn't work. It never times out.
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        as400.Open()
        adapter.Fill(dt) 'This is where it hangs
        as400.Close()
        adapter.Dispose()
        cmd.Dispose()
        Return dt
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try

End Function
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It may be the connection to the AS400 itself. Try this version which disposes of the object in a slightly different order:

```
Function ExecuteOLEDBQuery(cmdtext As String) As DataTable
    Using cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=IBMDA400;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=@@USERID;Password=@@PASSWORD;Data Source=@@SYSTEM")
        cn.Open()
        Using da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmdtext, cn)
            Dim dt = New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)
            Return dt
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: This will not work. There is no problems with the connection. Another SQL statement that will return something will work just fine. It's the SQL that will return nothing the hangs on the fill command.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that what it's getting isn't actually nothing, but rather a really large file that is causing the major slowdown.